# How do add a custom http module to a running Azure Webapp programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-management-api

I have a custom http module (.DLL developed in .NET) that I'd like to add /programmatically/ to a running Azure Web App.  I have access to management certificate or ARM token that WebApp is running under.  I'm using .NET code to talk to Azure Management API, so examples with their Management libraries are preferred

I've looked at the client.WebSites.UpdateConfiguration call and its HandlerMappings property, but these look to be Website extensions that are shown as HTML pages that help manage the WebApp, not analyze live traffic.

Basically, I need to add custom .NET DLL library that analyzes web requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of any specific way. But Can be Done in your App Start

Please Follow the link
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/register-your-http-modules-at-runtime.html